# Kolmogorov-Smirnov using R

Tags: r

Long story short, I want to manually write the code for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov one-sample statistic instead of using ks.test() in R. From what I understand, the K-S test can be broken down into a ratio between a numerator and a denominator. I am interested in writing out the numerator, and from what I understand it is the maximal absolute difference between a sample of observations and the theoretical assumption. Let's use the below case as an example:

```
         Data    Expected
1  0.01052632 0.008864266
2  0.02105263 0.010969529
13 0.05263158 0.018282548
20 0.06315789 0.031689751
22 0.09473684 0.046315789
24 0.26315789 0.210526316
26 0.27368421 0.220387812
27 0.29473684 0.236232687
28 0.30526316 0.252520776
3  0.42105263 0.365650970
4  0.42105263 0.372299169
5  0.45263158 0.398781163
6  0.49473684 0.452853186
7  0.50526316 0.460277008
8  0.73684211 0.656842105
9  0.74736842 0.665484765
10 0.75789474 0.691523546
11 0.77894737 0.718005540
12 0.80000000 0.735955679
14 0.84210526 0.791135734
15 0.86315789 0.809972299
16 0.88421053 0.838559557
17 0.89473684 0.857950139
18 0.96842105 0.958337950
19 0.97894737 0.968642659
21 0.97894737 0.979058172
23 0.98947368 0.989473684
25 1.00000000 1.000000000
```

Here, I want to obtain the maximal absolute difference (Data - Expected).

Anyone have an idea? I can rephrase this question, if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: What denominator? The statistic is a distance. Sometimes the distance is scaled for the asymptotic standard error of the distance, but personally I think of that as multiplication by a constant. Can you be explicit about what exact formula you mean by the KS statistic, and what the denominator is precisely? The difficulty is not so much evaluating the statistic, it's the finite sample distribution. How are you doing that?

Comment: @Glen_b I found the answer to the question. Posting it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for an answer something along the lines of this code:

```
> A <- with(df, max(abs(Data-Expected)))
```

,where df is the data frame.

Here, I obtain the differences between each Data and Expected, convert the values into absolute values, and from the vector of absolute differences select the maximum value. Thus, the answer is:

```
> A
0.082
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @Andy Looks to me like that's intended as an answer to the question